# Getting province and city name of given point

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap

OpenStreetMap has many shapefiles for downloading, and with `shp2pgsql` we can import it to PostGIS

> shp2pgsql -s SRID SHAPEFILE.shp SCHEMA.TABLE | psql -h HOST -d DATABASE -U USER

How can I get province and city name (or id) of a given point?

It is a little confusing for me! can someone explain more how can I do it? I just find some shape files here https://download.geofabrik.de/north-america/us.html and have no idea how to import just state/providence/city boundaries

Just tell me how to convert it to a minimal postgres table that contains `type (state or city)` , `name of state/city` and `geometry of state/city`

I know how can I use functions like `ST_Contains` to find city of given point

Comment: You need to add more precisions on your question. 1. What is exactly the question. How to use psql/postgresql to write a SQL request ? OR What is the request to filter the table ? 2. What is the structure of your table (i.e. her name and the name of the columns). You can show the structure of the table in the result of the ```sh2pqsql``` command. For this use this command ```shp2psql -p SHAPEFILE.shp``` and put the result in your question (it should be a short sql command with a  ```CREATE TABLE…``` command).

Comment: @Atm I updated the question